# Generate CSV with 2 Tables using Codigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, export

I have Two tables in DB. One is Lead and other lead note.. Lead and Lead note have foreign key relationship.. I want to generate a CSV so its have One lead column then All the notes related to that Lead..

[Here is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZLO3.jpg)
My current code is

```
    $all_leads = '';
    $name = 'leads-'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv';
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->db->select("lead_id as Lead ID,business_name as Business,contact_name as First Name,contact_name_last as Last Name,work_email as Email,contact_email as Personal Email,work_number as Work Number,cell_no as Cell No,city as City,state as State,zip as Zip,date_added as Date Added,IF( label_type <> 0,'Important',' ') as Label, companies.company_name as company name");
    $this->db->from('leads');
    $this->db->join('companies', 'companies.id = leads.company');
    $leads = $this->db->get();
    $num_rows = $leads->num_rows();

    $all_leads= $this->dbutil->csv_from_result( $leads );
    write_file( $this->file_path . '/'.$name,$all_leads );
    $data = file_get_contents($this->file_path . '/'.$name);

    force_download( $name, $data );
    delete_files( $this->file_path . '/'.$name );`
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share a piece of code which may help you. Al you have to do is to adjust the data as per your requirement. Please check the code below

```
<?php
    $this->db->select("a.lead_id,a.business_name,a.a.contact_name_first,a.contact_name_last,a.work_email,a.contact_email,a.work_number,a.cell_no,a.city,a.state,a.zip,a.date_added,IF( a.label_type <> 0,'Important',' ') as label, b.company_name");
    $this->db->from('leads a');
    $this->db->join('companies b', 'b.id = a.company');
    $this->db->join('lead_note c', 'c.lead_id = a.id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $delimiter = ",";
        $filename = "members_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

        //create a file pointer
        $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

        //set column headers
        $fields = array('Lead ID','Business','First Name','Last Name','Email','Personal Email','Work Number','Cell No','City','State','Zip','Date Added');

        //output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
        foreach($result as $row){

            $lineData = array($row['lead_id'], $row['contact_name_first'], $row['contact_name_last'], $row['work_email'], $row['contact_email'], $row['work_number'], $row['cell_no'], $row['city'], $row['state'], $row['zip'], $row['date_added'], $row['label'], $row['company_name']);
            fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
        }

        //move back to beginning of file
        fseek($f, 0);

        //set headers to download file rather than displayed
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

        //output all remaining data on a file pointer
        fpassthru($f);
    }
    exit;

    ?>
```

Hope this helps. Do not use spaces for aliasing and table names. If using spaces , you need to use back ticks correctly. I strongly recommend camelcase or undersoce naming convension for tables and aliases

Comment: This is got only one table data . how to fetch both table data for this code ?

Comment: was it helpful?

Comment: Please share full schema. I dont have complete understanding of your data. For joins, I need details regarding entire tables.

Comment: See the latest edit. Please let me know it it helped

Comment: i already tried with join but its not put on new line.. Also it repeats the lead

Comment: please share screenshot of the output you are getting

Comment: I did on my own let em share my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all to help.. I did in this way..

```
check_admin();
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
    $name = 'leads-'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv';
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name.'');  
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
    fputcsv($output, array('Lead ID', 'Business', 'First Name' ,'Last Name', 'Email','Work Number','Cell No','City','State','Zip','Date Added', 'Label','company name','Business', 'First Name' ,'Last Name', 'Email','Work Number','Cell No'));  
    $query = "SELECT leads.`lead_id`, leads.`business_name` as `Business`, leads.`contact_name` as `First Name`, leads.`contact_name_last` as `Last Name`, leads.`work_email` as `Email`, leads.`work_number` as `Work Number`, leads.`cell_no` as `Cell No`, `city` as `City`, `state` as `State`, `zip` as `Zip`, `date_added` as `Date Added`, IF( label_type <> 0, 'Important', ' ') as Label, `companies`.`company_name` as `company name`,lead_contact.`company_name` as `Business1`, lead_contact.`contact_name` as `First Name1`, lead_contact.`contact_name_last` as `Last Name1`, lead_contact.`work_email` as `Email1`, lead_contact.`work_number` as `Work Number1`, lead_contact.`cell_no` as `Cell No1` FROM `leads` Left JOIN `companies` ON `companies`.`id` = `leads`.`company` Left JOIN `lead_contact` ON `lead_contact`.`lead_id` = `leads`.`lead_id`"; 
    $all_leads = $this->db->query( $query ); 
    foreach ($all_leads->result_array( ) as $lead){
        $lead_id = $lead['lead_id'];
        $query = "SELECT `note_date`,`notes` from lead_notes where lead_id='$lead_id'";
        $leads_notes = $this->db->query($query);
        fputcsv($output, $lead);
        //fputcsv($output, array('','Lead ID', 'Added', 'Notes'));
    foreach ($leads_notes->result_array( ) as $leads_note){

        fputcsv($output, $leads_note);

    }

}
```